# Setting Start and End Date Parameters to cell references when executing a stored prodecure in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have the following code which declares variables and executes a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Start date
DECLARE @End date

EXEC client_report @Start, @End
```

I need the `@Start` to link to a cell reference which is the start date and `@End` has to link to another cell reference which is an end date, the aim is that when I click refresh, the data will show data that is between those dates.

Can anybody help here?

Comment: Although all of that sounds plausible, it's actually a lot of work, and there are many different ways to do this. I would actually question if there isn't a much better way to do this, e.g. write a report in SSRS, then export the results to Excel.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have all the data in Excel and you are trying to report through SQL Server?